# How get results using multiple selects with different where condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have four tables customers, orders, orderitems, and sales and I want to get the total amount due for each customer with balance for each customer. For that I have tried this SQL query:

```
SELECT c.name          AS CustomerName, 
       c.contactnumber AS CustomerContactNumber, 
       c.location      AS CustomerAddress, 
       SUM(oi.amount)  AS Amount, 
       SUM(t2.balance) AS Balance 
FROM   orderitems oi 
INNER JOIN orders o ON oi.orderid = o.id 
INNER JOIN customers c ON o.customerid = c.id 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT s.customerid, 
            SUM(s.balance) AS Balance 
     FROM   sales s 
     INNER JOIN customers c ON s.customerid = c.id 
     GROUP BY s.customerid) t2 ON t2.customerid = c.id 
WHERE o.status == 'Processing' 
GROUP BY 
    c.id, c.contactnumber, c.location
```

It generates following output:

[image: Output]

It correctly calculates the amount due, but it calculates the balance twice as the original balance for both customers is 100 each but it show 200 for each.

Also please note that order has a status column which will have "Processing" if the order amount is due and it will have "Incomplete" if it has some balance.

Table structures are:

Orders:

[image: Orders]

Sales:

[image: Sales]

OrderItems:

[image: OrderItems]

Customers:

[image: Customers]

Please help.

Comment: Do you have multiple `ContactNumber` or multiple `Location` for each `Curstomer`?

Comment: No, each customer has single record , and when a order et processed i save amount paid with balance in sales table and update the order status from processing to complete / incomplete based on balance in orders table.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hint:  The best way to "show" schema for database questions is to include CREATE TABLE statements, not images, especially not linked images.

Comment: How many orders does each customer has ? Is it 2 ? 
Why are you doing sum(balance) as part of join  and then again doing sum at the top level. Although very difficult to pin point without looking at data, but to me it looks like if the customer has multiple orderitems this query is not correct.

Comment: Don't join customers in the subquery.  You only need sales.

Comment: Honestly, there is not enough information to determine why you get incorrect balances, because you do not provide sample data that corresponds to the summary data lines that you show.  It could be because your main query joins on OrderItems.  That means the sum would be **re-calculated** for every OrderItem, because the join on the Sales subquery would be included for each OrderItem.  It could also be because you are summing "balances".  Any answer you get is likely guesses... even if they are correct, nobody can guess at how your data and schema work together without more detail.

Comment: Overall, you really should refactor your tables to support transactional records. It is poor practice to record received amounts and balances as single values that have been added elsewhere. Proper accounting practices would be to record each received amount and date separately, then add those up and subtract from order invoice amounts dynamically to get the balances. You will likely end up with inconsistent, mismatched data without a proper trail of expense to income if you keep this system. The key idea is data normalization... avoiding duplicate and/or aggregate table columns.

Comment: Thanks all, I have redesigned the tables and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You are summing the balance in the outer query but you should not be because it is summed in the subquery.  You can GROUP BY the balance (which isn't great design theory, but it is functional); or you could do a separate subquery for the sum(amount) and *then* join the balance without grouping.

```
SELECT c.name          AS CustomerName, 
       c.contactnumber AS CustomerContactNumber, 
       c.location      AS CustomerAddress, 
       SUM(oi.amount)  AS Amount, 
       t2.balance      AS Balance
FROM   orderitems oi 
INNER JOIN orders o ON oi.orderid = o.id 
INNER JOIN customers c ON o.customerid = c.id 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT customerid, SUM(balance) AS Balance
   FROM   sales
   GROUP BY customerid
) t2 ON t2.customerid = c.id 
WHERE o.status == 'Processing' 
GROUP BY c.id, c.contactnumber, c.location, c.name, t2.balance
```

As 2 subqueries:

```
SELECT c.name          AS CustomerName, 
       c.contactnumber AS CustomerContactNumber, 
       c.location      AS CustomerAddress, 
       t3.Amount       AS Amount,
       t2.balance      AS Balance
FROM   customers c
INNER JOIN ( -- subquery to return Amount for each customerid
   select o.customerid, sum(oi.amount) AS Amount
   FROM orderitems oi
   INNER JOIN orders o ON oi.orderid = o.id 
   GROUP BY o.customerid
   WHERE o.status == 'Processing'
) t3 on t3.cusomterid = c.id
INNER JOIN ( -- subquery to return balance for each customerid
   SELECT customerid, SUM(balance) AS Balance
   FROM   sales
   GROUP BY customerid
) t2 ON t2.customerid = c.id
```

Comment: suming the balance makes sense if there are multiple balances / sales per customer  grouping by the balance does not seem like it would ever be correct to me.

Comment: It only makes sense to sum it once -- which is done in the subquery.  Summing it AGAIN will effectively multiple the balance times the number of orders.

Comment: there should be only one row in the result of the sub-query -- it has a group by -- so the outer sum should have no effect AFAICT

Comment: The customer's balance is inner joined to EVERY order ITEM.  Then when it is later AGAIN grouped by and again summed it will be multiplied by the total number of items (not orders, as I said previously).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT c.name          AS CustomerName, 
       c.contactnumber AS CustomerContactNumber, 
       c.location      AS CustomerAddress, 
       SUM(oi.amount)  AS Amount, 
       SUM(s.balance) AS Balance 
FROM   orderitems oi 
INNER JOIN orders o ON oi.orderid = o.id 
INNER JOIN customers c ON o.customerid = c.id 
INNER JOIN sales s on c.id = s.customerid
WHERE o.status == 'Processing' 
GROUP BY 
    c.id, c.contactnumber, c.location
```

Comment: @CPerkins I am guessing.  Also pointing out this is functionally the same as the current code.

Comment: @CPerkins -- it is a fair point -- sometimes people post stuff that is not what they actually run (eg they simplify it for posting) and it shows how their original query was not correct (as here where there is a un-needed sub-query.)  Honestly, I don't really have a good reason, sometimes I do random shjt and see what sticks.